# Restore MySQL DB with Unicode characters (Arabic and Kurdish) in .gz format

Tags: mysql, unicode, arabic, database-restore, persian

I have a MySQL backup file in `.gz` format that was created by the backup wizard in cPanel.
When the restoration is done by the backup wizard, contents with  Arabic and Kurdish characters do not show correctly, even though I changed the collation to different UTF-8 encoding in PhpMyadmin.

For example, the real data in DB is : ***كامپى زانكۆ*** and the data showed after the restoring become to this : ***Ø¨ÙâØ²Ø§ÙÙÛÛâ***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common problem caused by inconsistent encoding schemes when creating and exporting the database. Here is the simplest way to solve it:

1. Import your backup file
2. Export it again, but using `latin1` encoding
3. Manually edit the exported file, change all occurrences of `latin1` to `utf8`.
4. Import the edited file.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply dear Ansari,
how to use latin1 encoding as the exporting encoding ?, where is it ?

Comment: @user1846458 if you're using phpmyadmin, just search for encoding options on the export page. If you have command-line access to mysql, use "mysqldump --default-character-set=latin1"

Comment: Dear Ansari,I use the Phpmyadmin,just utf-8,isoXXX, windows and other encoding are available ?!, There is no Latin1 on the export page

Comment: @user1846458 Note that latin1 is the same as ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

I added the lines

```
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

to the mysqld section of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on my new server, then exported the data using

`mysqldump oldDB --default-character-set=latin1 -r dbCopy.sql`

and imported it into the new DB using

`mysql> SOURCE dbCopy.sql`. Worked like a charm...