# PHP 5.4 - mySQL Arabic Characters

Tags: php, mysql, character, arabic

i have a webpage which is based on Smarty 3.3.2 and my webhoster networksolution.com upgraded my php version to the **PHP Version 5.4.17-pl0-gentoo** and all my arabic characters (database latin1 (tried to utf8 - no results)) are shown like: 
®Ù¾Ù„ §Ø±Ù¾®Ù¾Ù„ Ø§Ø­ØØ‡ Ø³Ø§Ø

This is the format like my database inserts but the mainly problem is that before my server was updated (it was 5.2.) it worked correctly, my header is already set up to utf-8

My template is shown correctly, so the problem is with the **mysql_query!**

Thanks!

Comment: you have to use utf throughout the ENTIRE rendering pipeline. browser->server->database->server->browser, or at least connect each stage with appropriate translation logic. Looks like you're using a different characterset at SOME stage in there, which is mangling the utf data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @Marc B is correct, you need to ensure that the data is treated as UTF-8 throughout the entire process ... form submission (from the client side); check the `charset` attribute on the `<form>` attribute, if that's how you're submitting the data... Check how the data is being procssed within PHP (before it gets to the database), and then ensure that the database table(s) you are inserting the data are also utf8. Also, some PHP methods have an encoding argument; which the default value could've changed in the version upgrade.

Comment: could someone explain this? because im using latin1 and before worked it perfectly.

Comment: i added this on my index.php from smarty
 // header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
 // ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
 // ini_set('mbstring.func_overload',7);
 // ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );

Comment: so how i should going on? tx.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17756002/802117

Comment: How should i do this? Manually edit the exported file, change all occurrences of latin1 to utf8.

Comment: So i tried it, the same problem. I exported it already like this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all please confirm that the arabic text is saving correctly in the database, if it is ok then just add following code just before your select query

```
mysql_query("set characer set utf8");
```

and add

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

this code

and if arabic text is not correctly saved in database then please change your database collation to UTF-8.