# Best character for arabic mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, arabic

I have old database with Arabic character columns, collection utf8_unicode_ci, but for values like Ø¨ØºØ¯Ø§Ø¯

I used [www.2cyr.com/decode/](http://www.2cyr.com/decode/) to convert from utf8 to iso8859-1 and it displayed بغداد

How I can convert from utf8 to iso8859-1 or fix problem via phpmyadmin?

Thanks

Comment: If the database is in utf-8 and the connection is in utf-8 and the web server serving phpMyAdmin is in utf-8, utf-8 chars should show up properly. In all other cases, you're puzzled with encodings and manually changing the field values would be the very last resort before checking all settings

Comment: is iso8859-1 same latin1_general_ci ?

Comment: Yepp, besides the "ci" which indicates "case independent": values like "AAA" and "aaa" are treated as equal in `order by` and `where` clauses.

Comment: now I used this code echo utf8_decode($var_from_db); it shown but not all char correct

Comment: As I said: it doesn't help tot try to fix a puzzled encodings settings on the very last line. Check, whether all and everythiong is set up properly to handle utf-8 chars and fix this. Transforming from one to another encoding (multibyte to singlebyte even) is never ever working properly.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17756257/802117